# How to deploy codeigniter in AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new in AWS Elastic Beanstalk so I don't have any idea how to solve the 403 forbidden everytime I try sample.elasticbeanstalk.com/ and 404 not found if itry sample.elasticbeanstalk.com/login. My codeigniter is working on my wampserver and also in linux server. Am I missing something? My controller filename first  letter is already in uppercase.

Here's my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  Options +Indexes
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /sample
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|user_assets|tmp|robots\.txt)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And my config.php in codeigniter:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

I hope someone can help me on how to setup codeigniter in AWS elastic beanstalk properly. Thank you

Comment: First thing you should check is your zip folder structure which you uploaded and deployed. Your codeigniter setup should not be in a nested folder i.e not like folder.zip/folder/codeigniter. It should be like folder.zip/codeigniter